# Client Id of Image is found to be null during page refresh with asp.net and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image

In asp.net, I have declared this image control on my aspx page:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/hourglass.gif" Enabled ="true" Visible="true" />
```

I have a button that triggers javascript to display an hourglass image while a database fetch is done:

```
<asp:button id="btnSearch" style="Z-INDEX: 103; LEFT: 257px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 60px; width: 149px; height: 29px;" tabIndex="5" runat="server" Text="Search Recent History" OnClientClick="return showhourglass();" ></asp:button>
```

Here is the showhourglass code in javascript:

```
function showhourglass() {

    document.getElementById('<%=Image1.ClientID%>').setAttribute("style","visibility:visible");

}
```

I have set up the javascript to wait until the resources are loaded before turning the image invisible:

```
$(window).on("load",function () { document.getElementById('<%=Image1.ClientID%>').setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden"); });
```

The image (hourglass) is invisible when the page is loaded as expected. I click the button and the hourglass does appear while the database fetches my data as expected. However, upon producing the data and filling the table, the "window.on("load",...) function then throws an exception and reports that the document.getElementById('Image1') is null.

So I have two questions. First, why is this null? The declaration of the image is outside of the form tag in the markup so isn't this is a partial page load? Shouldn't this image still be available for manipulation in the DOM?

Second question: Does the $window.on("load",...) get called anytime a single element is reloaded? Since subsequent clicks of the button produce a NULL in the (window).on("load",...), the showhourglass function also returns a NULL when trying to locate the image control. In other words, the page is loaded correctly, but after one button click, the image is returned as NULL by any and all javascript that attempts to reference it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: as a sidenote (assuming you're using .net 3.5 or higher) you can add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your Image tag- and then you don't have to use `'<%=Image1.ClientID%>'` you can just use `Image1`

Comment: Could it be due to the space in `< %=`?

Comment: No that is a typo as I pasted the code in here. There is no space in my code.